# How do I "dump" the contents of an X terminal programmatically a la /dev/vcs{,a} in the Linux console?

Tags: linux, terminal, console, screen-scraping, gnu-screen

Linux's kernel-level console/non-X terminal emulator contains a very cool feature <sup><sub>(if compiled in)</sub></sup>: each `/dev/ttyN` device corresponds with `/dev/vcsaN` and `/dev/vcsN` devices which represent the in-memory (displayed) state of that tty, with and without attributes (color, flashing, etc) respectively. This allows you to very easily `cat /dev/vcs7` and see a dump of `/dev/tty7` wherever `cat` was launched. 
I used this incredibly practical capability the other day to login to a system via SSH and remotely watch a `dd` process I'd forgotten to put inside a `screen` (or similar) session - it was running off a text console, so I took a few moments to finetune the character ranges that I wanted to grab, and presently I was watching `dd`'s transfer status over SSH (once every second, incidentally).

To reiterate and clarify, `/dev/vcs{,a}*` are character devices that retrieve the current in-memory representation the kernel console VT100 emulator, represented as a single "line" of text (there are no "newlines" at the end of each "line" of the screen). 
Just to remove confusion, I want to note that I can't `tail -f` this device: it's not a character stream like the TTY itself is. (But I've never needed this kind of behavior, for what it's worth.)

I've kept my ears perked for many years for a method to dump the character-cell memory state of X terminal emulators - or indeed any arbitrary process that needs to work with ttys, in some similar manner as I can with the Linux console. And... I am rather surprised that there is no practical solution to this problem - since it has, arguably, existed for approximately 30 years - X was introduced in 1984 - or, to be pedantic, at *least* 19 years - `/dev/vcs{,a}*` was introduced in kernel 1.1.94; the newest file in that release is dated 22 Feb 1995. <sup><sup>(The oldest is from 1st Dec 1993 :P)</sup></sup>

I would like to say that I do understand and realize that the tty itself is not a "screen buffer" as such but a character stream, and that the nonstandard feature I essentially exploited above is a quirky capability specific to the Linux VT102 emulator. However, this feature is cool enough (why else would it be in the mainline tree? <sup><sub>**:D**</sub></sup>) that, in my opinion, there **should** be a counterpart to it for things that work with `/dev/pts*`.

This afternoon, I needed to screen-scrape the output of an interactive ncurses application so I could extract metadata from the information it presented in my terminal. (There was no other practical way to achieve the goal I was aiming for.) Linux' kernel VT100 driver would permit such a task to be completed ***very*** easily, and I made the mistake of thinking that it, in light of this, it couldn't *truly* be that hard to do the same under X11.

By 9AM, I'd decided that the easiest way to experimentally request a dump of a remote screen would be to run it in [`dtach`](http://dtach.sf.net/) (think "`screen -x`" without any other options) and hack the `dtach` code to request a screen update and quit.

Around 11AM-12PM, I was requesting screen updates and dumping them to `stdout`.

Around 3:30PM, I accepted that using `dtach` would be impossible:

- First of all, it relies on the application itself to send the screen redraws on request, by design, to keep the code simple. This is great, but, as luck would have it, the application I was using didn't support whole-screen repaints - it would only redraw on screen-size change (and only if the screen size was truly different!).
- Running the program inside a `screen` session (because `screen` is a true terminal emulator and has an internal 2D character-cell buffer), then running `screen -x` inside `dtach`, also mysteriously failed to produce character cell updates.

I have previously examined `screen` and found the code sufficiently insane enough to remove any inclinations I might otherwise have to hack on it; all I can say is that said insanity may be one of the reasons `screen` does not already have the capabilities I have presented here (which would arguably be very easy to implement).

Other questions similar to this one frequently get answers to use typescript, or `script`; I just want to clarify that `script` saves *the stream of the tty itself* to a file, which I would need to push through a VT100 emulator to obtain a screen image of the current state of the tty in question. In other words, `script` would be a very insane solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not marking this as accepted since it doesn't solve the actual core issue (which is many years old), but I was able to achieve the specific goal I set out to do.

My specific requirements were that I wanted to screen-scrape the output of the [`ncdu`](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/) interactive disk usage browser, so I could simply press Enter in another terminal (or perform some similar, easy sequence) to add the directory currently highlighted/selected in `ncdu` to a file-list of files I wanted to work with.
My goal was not to have to distract myself with endless copy+paste and/or retyping of directory names (probably with not a few inaccuracies to boot), so I could focus on the directories I wanted to select.

`screen` has a refresh feature, accessed by pressing (by default) <kbd>CTRL+A, CTRL+L</kbd>. I extended my copy of `dtach` to be capable of sending keystrokes in addition to dumping remote screens to stdout, and wrapped `dtach` in a script that transmitted the refresh sequence (`\001\014`) to `screen -x` running inside `dtach`. This worked perfectly, retrieving complete screen updates without any flicker.

I will warn anyone interested in trying this technique, however, that you will need to perfect the art of dodging VT100 escape sequences. I used regular expressions for this so I wasn't writing thousands of lines of code; here's the specific part of the script that extracted out the two pieces of information I needed:

`sh -c "(sleep 0.1; dtach -k qq $'\001\014') &"; path="$(dtach -d qq -t 130000 | sed -n $'/^\033\[7m.*\/\.\./q;/---.*$/{s/.*--- //;s/ -\+.*//;h};/^\033\[7m/{s/.\033.*//g;s/\r.*//g;s/ *$//g;s/^\033\[7m *[^ ]\+ \[[# ]*\] *\(\/*\)\(.*\)$/\/\\2\\1/;p;g;p;q}' | sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/')"`

Since screenshots are cool and help people visualize things, here's a look at how it works when it's running:
[image: Screenshot of ncdu-scrape]

The file shown inverted at the bottom of the ncdu-scrape window is being screen-scraped from the ncdu window itself; the four files in the list are there because I selected them using the arrow keys in `ncdu`, moved my mouse over to the ncdu-scrape window (I use focus-follows-mouse), and pressed Enter. That added the file to the list (a simple text file itself).

Having said this, I would like to clarify that the regular expression above is not a code sample to run with; it is, rather, a warning: for anything beyond incredibly **trivial** (*!!*) content extractions such as the one presented here, you're basically getting into the same territory as large corporations/interests who want to convert from VT100-based systems to something more modern, who have to spend tends of thousands commissioning large translation frameworks that perform the kind of conversion outlined above on an especially large scale.

Saner solutions appreciated.